# Нужна книга/сайт с описанием тонкой настройки windows 10

Tags: windows, settings

Ищу книгу (или сайт) с описанием основных компонентов windows 10. Например - реестра, и тонкостей работы с ним. Скачал книгу "Внутреннее устройство Windows" Марка Руссиновича, но до нее еще не дорос, как оказалось. Нашел кучу самоучителей, в которых описывается, что такое файл или папка, и как работать с браузером, но это уже не нужно. А среднего ничего не нашел. Подскажите, где взять?

Comment: А тебе что тонко настраивать-то нужно?

Comment: Просто хочу знать устройство винды, чтобы знать каким образом исправить ту или иную проблему (бытовую).

Comment: Тогда лучше http://www.outsidethebox.ms, https://windowsnotes.ru и https://winitpro.ru/ выручали уже хрен знает сколько раз.

Comment: Спасибо, don Rumata!